# Anylogic How to seize multiple patients (2-3) with a single doctor

Tags: anylogic

I'm wondering how to use a seize function in Anylogic.

I would like to a doctor (resource) can seize multiple patients (coming from sources) at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't seize multiple agents with one resource without doing some sort of trick, and the trick depends on your problem... This is an example where you batch and unbatch agents before and after the seize.

Be careful on how you release the resource if you are separating the patients with the unbatch.

[image: batch patients]

Comment: Thanks! will try this one and let you know!